# iframe onload event fire after appending it into some div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

iframe onload event fire after appending it into some div.
Here is a part of code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  addContent(element, items[i], loadData_.bind(this, i, items));
}

function appendNew(element, item, cb) {
  var itemContainer = $('<div>')
    .addClass('someclass');
  var chart = $('<iframe>')
    .css('height', 677)
    .attr('frameBorder', "0")
    .attr('scrolling', 'no')
    .on('load', function() {
      cb();
    });
  itemContainer.append(chart);
  tabContent.append(itemContainer);
}
```

So, now after this code   `tabContent.append(itemContainer);`    load event fired. Why this event fires, while I not set src and load some content?
Has any idea?

Comment: load event fires when a resource is loaded. Setting src property has nothing to do with load event.

Answer (score 2):

Though you don't set the src **a blank iframe renders into the content**. That's why the onload function triggered.

[image]

Comment: Set the SRC before appending in a normal scenario..other wise bind the function after adding SRC..

Answer (score 1):

In the case of an `iframe`, the `onload` event fires when the `iframe` is loaded. When an `iframe` is added to your HTML, it is loaded, so this is why the `onload` is being executed. On attribute changes it is loaded again. You will need to add the load event handler to your `iframe` after you have added it to the HTML. Read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp